# LayerList not drawing properly dynamically

Tags: android

I want to create a Drawable programatically and set as background to TextView as below

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item>
<shape android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="@color/listitem_background_color" />
</shape>
</item>
<item android:top="44dp">
<shape android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="#7e000000" android:startColor="#7e5b5b5b" />
</shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Image showing two textview, 1. With larger width is having the background drawable set

[image: LayerList Drawable Set]

So as you can see the lower shadow border which i have given is through the 2nd item of layer list.

But when I try to do same programatically like this,

```
    Drawable[] layers = new Drawable[2];
    ShapeDrawable backgroundRect = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
    backgroundRect.getPaint().setColor(Color.parseColor(familyColor));


    int startColor = Color.parseColor("#7e5b5b5b");
    int endColor = Color.parseColor("#7e000000");
    GradientDrawable lowerShadow = new GradientDrawable(Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, new int[]{startColor, endColor});
    lowerShadow.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);

    layers[0] = backgroundRect;
    layers[1] = lowerShadow;
    LayerDrawable layerDB = new LayerDrawable(layers);
    layerDB.setLayerInset(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    layerDB.setLayerInset(1, 0, 20, 0, 0);

    familyHeaderView.setBackgroundDrawable(layerDB);
```

The view looks like this. As you can see the shadow which i want to be at the bottom is in centre.

[image: problem with the shadow]

Please help me with this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: *As you can see the shadow which i want to be at the bottom is in centre* - how exactly did you come up with `20` as the value for layer's top inset?

Comment: why would it be at the bottom?

Comment: I don't know the solution that's why I am asking. @Luksprog I don't know, i was just trying out with random values and 20 showed me a nearby look.

Comment: @pskink I want to draw a rectangle with gradient that way only which would give look and feel of some shadow of textview.

Comment: in xml you have android:top="44dp" while in java (0, 20, 0, 0) those numbers should match

Comment: @pskink i tried giving same values but not working :(

Comment: of course you made conversion: dp => px ?